# Excel Time calculation based on just one column?

Tags: excel, time

I have an excel sheet having time Column. I want to calculate the total time.
The excel column look like this:

Time:

2:14:53 , 2:15:53 ,  2:16:53 ,  2:19:53 ,  2:29:53 ,  2:41:53 ,    2:59:53

Now I want to calculate the  total time without adding any extra column or whatever ?

Comment: You need to define what the times represent, If you just want to add the times, then Peter's answer will do the job. But if there is a relationship, like the difference between times, then you would need to define what that relationship is.

Comment: @Jamejenkins There is no relationship b/w times, I just want to know the total duration of time.

Comment: Just to be clear, the time values you show are elapsed times (such as, it took 2 hours, 14 minutes, and 53 seconds for this event to occur)?  By the way, if you've received an answer that you found helpful, be sure to accept it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the times are time stamps and you're only interested in the delta between the first and the last entry, simply use `=A7-A1` - this will return the delta. In case it span across multiple days and you're only interested in the delta "on the watch", use `=MOD(A7-A1,1)`. Note that sometimes the result might be displayed as a normal numeric value (in this example `0.03125`instead of `0:45:00`). In this case, simply change the format to Time.

In case you're talking about lap times and you want to sum them up, you can simply do this with a `SUM` formula: `=SUM(A1:A7)` will return you the total time.

Here's your example:
[image]

Comment: I used Sum formula , but it gives me result like this 21:36, when i calculate it manually it should be 24 ?

Comment: the example you provided in your question results in 17:19:11 (see screenshot in the updated answer). Don't know where you get 21:36 or 24 from...

Comment: I want to know when you apply the formula on it, This should give us result in minutes as we want to calculate the time. But it is giving us result in 17:19:11 ? Rather than 45 Mints So how can you get the total in minutes ?

Comment: I cannot follow your question: where do you want to get 45 minutes from? In the example you provided, you list 2h:14min:53 seconds and so forth - the sum of all these is 17 hours, 19 minutes and 11 seconds...

Comment: I used formula =(MOD(A7-A1,1))

Comment: Ahh! So you wanted only the delta between the first and the last cell and not the "total" (=the sum) of all cells! Yes, in that case your solution will work and return `0:45:00`. I'll adjust the answer... Is the problem solved then?

Comment: Will add another screenshot when back online tonight